# Tools for optimizing XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm making a Windows Store App. Unfortunately it has some performance issues on weaker ARM devices. After reading [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994641.aspx) about how to optimize the loading of XAML, I'm interested if there is any tool that will allow me to see a tree of where resources are referenced and/or help me optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a visual tree you can use [Document Outline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602283%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in VS. Some other handy XAML tools are like [WPF Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), or [Silverlight Spy](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy), but most of all just good 'ol Expression Blend is a dear friend when working with xaml & templates. Hope this helps.